# Linq collection with not like?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I have a dataGridView with multiple server roles. I'd like to get a collection of server names with roles "not like" webSrvr or client. For example.. DGV:

```
Servers | Server 1 | Server 2 | Server 3 | Server 4 | Server 5 
Role    | Database | Proxy    | WebSrvr  | Client   | DC
```

Is there an easy linq statement to pull the Server 1, 2 and 5 column headers (names)? The reason I'd want to use "not like" or the equivalent is because the roles can have additional values at the end of it. Thoughts?

Comment: If your question been answered, maybe mark as answered?

Answer (score 0):

You could do pretty much what you want ...

```
var your_name = from str in your_list_source_here          
             where (str == some_condition)
             select ( new { create your object here } )
```

you could just have the columns you want in the `create your object here`

here's an example from [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) , to illustrate how you can use the new object ...

```
var words =
    from word in "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".Split()
    orderby word.ToUpper()
    select word;

var duplicates =
    from word in words
    group word.ToUpper() by word.ToUpper() into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

His objects will have the letter and the amount of time it repeats...

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. For some reason, Linq seems backwards to me and is still confusing.. I'll play around with it.

Comment: It's great once you get your feet around it ... oh, I didn't link the linq ...have a look at that tool, i'll update the post in a sec. It'll help you wrap your head around it ...